# Microsoft Outlook Web & Desktop + Add-in

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Does someone know why add-in appears on Outlook Desktop Scheduling Assistant when it shouldn't?In Outlook Web Scheduling Assistant the add-in does not appear, here it makes sense does not appear. **Is it a bug on Outlook Desktop?** See in Outlook Desktop that add-ins does not appear under Scheduling Assistant tab!

Outlook Web - New scheduling (normal):

[image]

Outlook Web - New scheduling assistant:

[image]

Outlook Desktop - New Scheduling (normal):

[image]

**Outlook Desktop - New scheduling assistant!!!**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Outlook desktop, the behavior that addin stays open when the user switches to the scheduling tab is by design. We believe this behavior is suitable for the desktop Outlook UI. This behavior lets the user to continue to use addin when the user is viewing the scheduling assistant.

Comment: I understand but its strange to have two different behaviours for one "same software". For us developers, the impossibility of detection which screen the add-in is working is related to office-js (https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js)?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are differences between the two clients. So there will be differences like this. Presumably, there may be some apps that would want OWA to behave the way Outlook Desktop does. A way to detect what page is showing, or to suggest a change in behavior one way or another should be made to our UserVoice: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins