# How to detect which screen the add-in is working inside Outlook for Desktop and Outlook Web?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

According to [this issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1021#issuecomment-593266280) and [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60435454/microsoft-outlook-web-desktop-add-in/60441711), I'd like to detect when my add-in is opened in Scheduling Assistant window. How to detect it with office-js inside Outlook Desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible currently. As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60435454/microsoft-outlook-web-desktop-add-in/60441711) post you can suggest this feature at:

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins